# How much protein per 100g is considered "high protein"?

Tags: nutrition, diet, proteins

I've just opened my first ever USN "Pro Protein" premium multi-protein bar.

Its a **68g bar** with **20.1g protein** in it. That's less than 1/3rd protein. Good news is it tastes pretty good...

Anyway, the nutritional information says that it contains **29.6g protein per 100g** - still less than 1/3rd protein.

I was wondering, is this considered a high protein supplement? I would have expected "high protein" to mean that protein content is closer to at least 50% protein...

Comment: I think a better question is how much total protein should one have in a day.  I get about 105 g/day and it is too much as indicated by a high  BUN blood test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the E.U. the European Commission consider a product labeled as or 'claims' to be a source of protein must contain at least 12% and a high-protein product — or one labeled as such to likely have the same meaning for the consumer must be at least 20% protein.

> A nutritional 'claim' means any claim which states, suggests or
>   implies that a food has particular beneficial nutritional properties
>   due to:
>
> 1. The energy (calorific value) it:
>
>    - (a) provides
>    - (b) provides at a reduced or increased rate or
>    - (c) does not provide
> 2. The nutrients or other substances it:
>
>    - (a) contains
>    - (b) contains in reduced or increased proportions or
>    - (c) does not contain

Your bar then — having 29.6% protein — is indeed high-protein. In the E.U.

In the U.S. it is more difficult to define.

The Food & Drug Administration state:

In the U.S., similarly a product "high," "rich in" or described in "excellent source of":

> Contains 20% or more of the DV per RACC. May be used on meals or main
>   dishes to indicate that the product contains a food that meets the
>   definition, but may not be used to describe the meal.

DV being Percent Daily Value and RACC being Reference Amounts Customarily Consumed.

From the Frequently Asked Questions for Industry on Nutrition Facts Labeling Requirements factsheet the RACC for most cooked meats and fish is 85g.

So for a meat to be high-protein it must have 17g (20%) of protein if the RACC was 85g.

This would vary by protein source, however.

**In general, the 20% mark is considered to be high-protein.**